# DRF clear m2m field via patch with SlugRelatedField

Tags: django-rest-framework

Currently i'm using a SlugRelatedField in my ModelSerializer to represent a m2m-Field.

```
manager = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
                     many=True, 
                     queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),
                     slug_field='username', 
                     required=False,
                     allow_null=True)
```

if i send now a patch request with e.g.
`'manager': 'user1'` or `'manager: ['user1', 'user2']` it works as expected.

but how can i achieve, that the m2m field gets cleared, when i send an empty array `'manager': []`

at the moment nothing happens, when i do so.
If i try to clear it with `'manager': ''` i get an "object with username= does not exist" error.

maybe the SlugRelatedField isn't the right choice for me? i just wanted to achieve handling users with their username instead of their pk.

**Edit:**

I can do a PUT Request with not sending 'manager' at all to clear it.
Is there maybe no way to clear a m2m field with a PATCH Request?

`r = requests.patch('http://localhost:8000/api/projects/dfo2/',
                    auth = ('lala','lilu'), 
                    data = {'developer': []}
                    )`

result:

`{'manager': ['peter', 'fllow'], 'description': '','name_short': 'dfo2',  'developer': ['peter'], 'name': 'asdf'}`

what works is:

```
r = requests.patch('http://localhost:8000/api/projects/dfo2/',
                auth = ('lala','lilu'), 
                data = '{"developer": []}',
                headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
                )
```

but why does this not work:

```
r = requests.patch('http://localhost:8000/api/projects/dfo2/',
                auth = ('lala','lilu'), 
                data = {"developer": []},
                headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code it is hard to know, but generally it seems like you are not dealing with the data properly.  One piece of advice I always give people with `DRF` is to think about serializers as a tool for giving and validating data, but not necessarily describing what to do with it.

With that in mind, I suggest you try something like the following, although again it is hard without seeing the models and full serializer code:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    managers = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Users')


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    managers = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
                     many=True,
                     source='managers.all',
                     queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),
                     slug_field='username', 
                     required=False,
                     allow_null=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        [instance.managers.add(manager) for manager in validated_data['managers']
        return instance
```